# Multiple OR conditions in if statements

Tags: java

I have created a method that uses an iterator that iterates through a map and for each pair it evaluates a statement with many OR conditions. If the condition is true, it adds the object of the pair (a Notification object) in a list (anomalies). However, at compilation time, the compiler gives a NullPointerException exception at this method. Based on my investigation, it seems that there is a problem in the if statement, but I can't see why. Can anyone give me an help in this? Thanks!

```
public List<Notification> getAnomalies(NotificationSearchCriteria notificationSearchCriteria) {

 Map<String,Notification> messageList = new HashMap<String,Notification>();
List<Notification> anomalies = new ArrayList<Notification>();

Iterator iterator = messageList.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
    Notification message = (Notification) pairs.getValue();

           if(message.getDescription().equals(notificationSearchCriteria.getDescription())||message.getSubjectName().equals(notificationSearchCriteria.getSubjectName())||message.getNotificationSubject().toString().equals(notificationSearchCriteria.getNotificationSubject().toString())||message.getNotificationType().toString().equals(notificationSearchCriteria.getNotificationType().toString())){

               anomalies.add(message);

             }
        }

    }
    return anomalies;
}
```

Comment: Before the `if` statement, print out each of the objects you're examining (`message.getDescription()`, `notificationSearchCriteria.getDescription()`, etc.) to make sure none of those is `null`. My guess is one of them is not being assigned somewhere.

Comment: `NullPointerException` occurs at runtime, **never** at compile time.

Comment: Your if statement doesn't look wrong, but a NullPointerException to me sounds like one of the objects in the if statement are indeed null.  I would ensure that notificationSearchCriteria is not null when it is passed into the function and see if that helps.

Comment: Split up this huge `if` in several simple `if` statements. This makes it easier to find such bugs and to maintain such code.

Comment: maybe revert tghe if statement - what has to be false to get you in?

Comment: This begs for refactoring...

Comment: "However, at compilation time, the compiler gives a NullPointerException exception at this method." No it doesn't. I've never seen the compiler throw an NPE in nearly 16 years. You are getting this *at run-time,* and you are getting it because you dereferenced a null value.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by one of the methods on `message` returning null.  For example, if `message.getDescription()` returns null, then `message.getDescription().equals(<something>)` will throw a `NullPointerException`, since you can't call additional methods on a null object.

There are several ways to fix this.  First off, I recommend inspecting your objects to see which can return a null value and add the appropriate handling code.

More generally, I always recommend calling equals on the variable you know not to be null to avoid these problems.  For example

```
if ("accept".equals(command)) {
  // do something
}
```

is generally better than

```
if (command.equals("accept")) {
 // do something
}
```

because the second might through an NPE, while the first never will.

Comment: You are right, using the string literal and calling `equals()` on it is the safer way to do it, but it's not applicable in this case as the OP doesn't know `a` or `b` in his `a.equals(b)`.

Comment: It's still applicable, you just need more of the code to know for sure.  For example, does the implementation of NotificationCenter guarantee to never return null?  If so, use that as the base of the equals

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the message-matching code into the `NotificationSearchCriteria` class. The `if` would end up being "if (notificationSearchCriteria.matches(message))". From the names, I am guessing that is `NotificationSearchCriteria`'s only usage; in that sense, it would not increase coupling.

The check-for-null would be performed during `NotificationSearchCriteria` construction; which would ensure that all fields were non-null. In the matching code, within that class, things would look like:

```
boolean matches(Notification message) {
   if (description.equals(message.getDescription()) ||  // LHS guaranteed non-null
      foo.equals(message.getFoo()) ||
      bar.equals(message.getBar()) || // ...
   ) { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to code is to do null check.

Ideally I would have code like this :

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
    Notification message = (Notification) pairs.getValue();
          if(null!=message && null!=message.getDescription() &&        
               null!=notificationSearchCriteria.getDescription() )
          {
             //Do your comparioson
          }else{
           //Handle the NullPointerException error the way you want
          }
  }
```